# Stopping while loops in Flutter with button clicks

Tags: flutter, dart, while-loop

How do I stop a while loop with a button press.

```
 while (thirdDigit <= 9 && stopLoop == false) {
  while (sixDigits <= 999999 && stopLoop == false) {
    perspective = prefix + thirdDigit.toString() + sixDigits.toString();
    url = perspective + urlSuffix;

    validateUrl(url, numberListTiles, perspective);
    print('BotStore: $url');
    sixDigits++;
  }
  thirdDigit++;
}
```

}

I want this loop to be stopped when I click on a button and assign stopLoop = true.

But no matter how many times I press the stop button, the loop is running in the main thread and the button does not stops the loop.

How do I run the loop in the background and still have a functioning app?

Answer (score 1):

To run the loop in the background, put it in an async function :

```
Future<void> loop() async {
    // Loop here
}
```

To stop it on the tap of a button, set stopLoop to true inside a setState() :

```
onPressed: () => setState(() => stopLoop = true);
```

Comment: Dart is single threaded, so nothing runs "in the background". Making the function asynchronous does allow it to release control to other code, but it has to do so at some point, otherwise the loop will run to completion before any other code gets to run, including UI click handlers.

Comment: Actually some would argue that Dart isn't technically single-threaded because it takes advantage of multi-core CPUs, and also you can spawn separate Isolates from the main one. Anyway, I meant background as opposed to blocking the event loop.

Comment: Making the function asynchronous *allows* it to relinquish control, but you still have to add some `await` or other asynchronous delay to the loop code itself, other the single-threaded execution will still not be interrupted. Dart may allow multiple isolates, but they are isolated and cannot affect each other's execution except by sending messages, and each isolate is single-threaded. That's why nothing can interrupt a tight loop.

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, the loop is running and hogging the main thread. You need to introduce some points where the UI can interrupt the code.

First make sure that your function is `async`.
Then add a line like:

```dart
  await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
```

in your loop. You decide whether to put it in the inner or the outer loop, depending on how often you want to allow other code to run.